# Scrolling one page in Yii2

Tags: header, yii2

One page scrolling in Yii2, I want to give section `id` to 'about us' menu and
my code is:

```
NavBar::begin([
    //'brandLabel' => 'abc',
    'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/images/logo.png'),
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ['label' => 'About Us', 'url' => ['/site/index'], '#' => 'aboutusSec'],
];
```

Above code not working for me. Please can anyone help?

Comment: Try `'url' => ['/site/index', '#' => 'aboutusSec']`

Comment: Wow,its working....Very thankful for your immediate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single array:

```
NavBar::begin([
    //'brandLabel' => 'abc',
    'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/images/logo.png'),
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ['label' => 'About Us', 'url' => ['/site/index', '#' => 'aboutusSec'],]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as below:

```
        $menuItems = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About Us', 'url' => ['/#aboutusSec']],]
```

Then add following rules to your URLManager:

```
'rules'=>[
         '' => 'site/index',
         '#aboutusSec' => '/#aboutusSec',
```